# How many can be formed??

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm not sure if this is supposed to be Permutation, Combination, or neither?

The Question is: Determine the number of five-letter code words that can be formed from the word "mommy"

What I did was just do $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$. However, it says that the answer is wrong. Can someone explain why it's not what I did and how I should approach this question? Thank you in advance

Comment: This is a [permutation of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets).

Answer (score 1):

$5\times4\times3\times2\times1$ is incorrect because you didn't account for the repeated $m$. Since there are $3$ m's, you need to divide by $3!$, or the number of ways to rearrange the repeated $m$'s. Thus the result would be $\dfrac{5!}{3!}$ or $20$.

Comment: but shouldn't the m not matter because the order matters? since they would all be considered different m's.

Comment: @c9c9c9c9c9c9 Why are they different?

Comment: since they're are 3 different m's. but the person below explained so now i understand. so thank you!

Comment: Since they look the same they are considered the same and glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The letter $m$ are not distinguishable. You have to avoid over counting.

For example: If you label the $m$'s by the subscript $1$ , $2$, and $3$

then $m_1om_2m_3y$ and $m_2om_1m_3y$ are different.

However, in this particular setting, they are not labelled, hence you need to divide away the redundancy, which is $3!$.

Comment: ohh i see. thank you!